# How to make a lazy susan 'lift'?

Tags: mechanisms

I want to make a smaller version of a revolving stage with rotation and lift.
But how do you combine those mechanism that creates a turntable and that rotates and lifts up at the same time? I know that you can use a slip ring, but how do you put that together to make a lift?

Also there are lots of tutorials about the lazy susan but no lift... Does anyone has a simular tutorial on how to make this?

And if you want to recycle an old printer which part could you use the best to make this rotating-lift up-turntable like a revolving stage?

Comment: Unlikely anything in the printer, other than using the motors to drive your assembly, will be of use.  All the ones I'm familiar with use belt drives rather than worm drives.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of simple lifting mechanisms there are a few good options.

A [scissor lift](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=scissor%20lift%20how%20it%20works&safe=off&rlz=1C1GIWA_enGB625GB625&espv=2&biw=1440&bih=770&tbm=isch&imgil=j8QJT7vf2ozm2M%253A%253ByZ3_C-JOaY28VM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.globalspec.com%25252Flearnmore%25252Fmaterial_handling_packaging_equipment%25252Fmaterial_handling_equipment%25252Fscissor_lifts&source=iu&pf=m&fir=j8QJT7vf2ozm2M%253A%252CyZ3_C-JOaY28VM%252C_&usg=__o6xcmxa2T9vRs9m_FXGhP8T1Lxc%3D&ved=0ahUKEwj6q7Gr9OTRAhWmKMAKHZVtAmQQyjcIkQE&ei=rZeMWLqhI6bRgAaV24mgBg#safe=off&tbm=isch&q=scissor%20lift%20) type  mechanism is reasonably simple and can be powered b y a lead screw. Depending on the number of elements you have it can get quite a lot of lift for a fairly compact footprint and retracted volume. They also give quite a large mechanical advantage and so can be operated with a fairly small motor driving a lead-screw.

another option is a [rack and pinion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rack_and_pinion) type mechanism, also reasonably simple but it doesn't actually collapse as such so you need space underneath for the column to retract into.